# Службы(сервисы) в DDD

Tags: архитектура, service, ddd, aggregate

Правильно ли я понимаю, как следует работать с агрегатами в DDD?

Допустим у нас есть агрегат1 и агрегат2, они связаны между собой по ссылке через id и напрямую не хранят друг друга. Но, скажем для отображения на уровне представления, они нужны совместно. Для этого мне необходимо создать службу прикладного уровня, в которой я вызову вызову методы репозиториев для получения этих агрегатов, далее создам какой-то DTO объект, заполню соответствующие поля и передам этот объект на уровень представления.

Примерно так же я поступлю, в случае получения каких-то запросов с уровня представления для изменения этих объектов, в методе сервиса прикладного уровня получу DTO объект, вытащу агрегаты с помощью репозиториев, сделаю с ними необходимые изменения и сохраню их так же через репозитории.

А вот если над агрегатом1 и агрегатом2 нужно будет выполнить какое-то совместное действие, которое будет являться частью модели предметной области, но не будет относиться напрямую к ответственности ни одного из агрегатов, то мне нужно будет создать службу предметной области, в методах которой я буду использовать только интерфейсы репозирториев, а реализации будут подставляться по принципу инверсии зависимости?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Примерно так же я поступлю, в случае получения каких-то запросов с уровня представления для изменения этих объектов, в методе сервиса прикладного уровня получу DTO объект, вытащу агрегаты с помощью репозиториев, сделаю с ними необходимые изменения и сохраню их так же через репозитории.
>
> А вот если над агрегатом1 и агрегатом2 нужно будет выполнить какое-то совместное действие, которое будет являться частью модели предметной области, но не будет относиться напрямую к ответственности ни одного из агрегатов, то мне нужно будет создать службу предметной области, в методах которой я буду использовать только интерфейсы репозирториев, а реализации будут подставляться по принципу инверсии зависимости?

Вы всё понимаете правильно.

На всякий случай уточню некоторые моменты. Службы прикладного уровня и службы предметной области очень похожи.

У них нет состояния, они реализуют бизнес-процессы. Важный момент — каждый метод службы создаёт свою собственную транзакцию, все операции выполняются внутри неё. Это важнейшая подсказка: если вам нужны свойства транзакции (атомарность, согласованность), значит, речь идёт о методе службы.

Службы работают с сущностями и объектами-значениями непосредственно. Здесь не нужны дополнительные уровни наследования, интерфейсы и прочее.

В приложении также будут службы *инфраструктурного уровня*. По сути репозитории — частный случай таких служб, который отвечает за хранение. Помимо хранения данных вы можете отправлять SMS, электронные письма или push-уведомления. Вы можете строить маршруты между адресами или отправлять сообщения в Telegram.

Эти службы должны быть доступны на уровне предметной области, но вы не можете их там реализовать, потому что реализация будет меняться. На уровне предметной области вы описываете интерфейс, достаточный для ваших нужд.

Предположим, что бизнес хочет присылать письмо покупателю, когда в книжном интернет-магазине появляется нужная книга.

На уровне предметной области вы можете не знать ничего об адресе пользователя, теме письма, шаблонах, и прочих технических деталях. У вас это может быть что-то такое:

```
interface INotificationService
{
   . . .
   void NotifyOfBooksAppearance(User user, IEnumerable<Book> books);
   . . .
}
```

Интерфейсы описаны на уровне предметной области и также доступны из служб предметной области. Их реализации находятся ниже — на инфраструктурном уровне.

Службы предметной области получают их через **внедрение зависимостей**, здесь вы совершенно правы.

Последний вопрос — отличие служб прикладного уровня и служб предметной области. Разница между ними настолько тонкая, что в большинстве случаев её просто нет. Это значит, что все соображения о том, как делать службы одного уровня можно применять к службам другого.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.